# pandas dataframe manipulation with DictVectorize

Tags: python, pandas

What I have:

| target | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jack, jones, phil | en-us |
| 0 | don, sam, bob | vn-en |
| 1 | jones, alex, sam | en-us |

What I want:

| var1 | target | no_target | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jones | 2 | 0 | en-us |

target column is how much 'jones' appears when target is 1

so far I have tried to use DictVetorize, and it helped me to count number of times target equal to 1 for jones
but I done know how to get var2 column

Comment: Not sure why you need `DictVectorize`, nor what the `no_target` column should be

Comment: @mozway no_target, how many times it appears when target equals zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df['target'].mul(df['var1'].str.count('jones')).sum()
```

output: `2`

For a more generic method to get all names:

```
out = (df
 .assign(var1=df['var1'].str.split(',\s*').where(df['target'].eq(1)))
 .explode('var1')
 .groupby(['var1', 'var2'], as_index=False)
 .sum()
)
```

output:

```
    var1   var2  target
0   alex  en-us       1
1   jack  en-us       1
2  jones  en-us       2
3   phil  en-us       1
4    sam  en-us       1
```

##### counting target/no_target

```
(df
 .assign(var1=df['var1'].str.split(',\s*'),
         target=np.where(df['target'].eq(1), 'target', 'no_target'),
         value=1
        )
 .explode('var1')
 .pivot_table(index=['var1', 'var2'], columns='target', values='value',
              aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
 .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
 .groupby(['var1'], as_index=False)
 .agg({'target': 'sum', 'no_target': 'sum', 'var2': 'first'})
)
```

output:

```
    var1  target  no_target   var2
0   alex       1          0  en-us
1    bob       0          1  vn-en
2    don       0          1  vn-en
3   jack       1          0  en-us
4  jones       2          0  en-us
5   phil       1          0  en-us
6    sam       1          1  en-us
```

Comment: wow! great solution!!
but one thing is missing, column "no_target" so how many times it appears when target equals zero

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain it in the question as I should have done

Comment: See update, slightly more complex

Comment: Mozway, can you plaese help with one last thing? fro example, above we have var1 "sam" appears with var2 "en-us" and "vn-en"
is it possible to combine these two in terms of number of appearance, and leave the first var2 that it had?
e.g:
sam |en-us| 1 ( as for no_target)| 1 (as for target)|

Comment: Yes, just don't group by `var2`

Comment: so I remove it from pivot_table as well, right?

Comment: I cleanest might be to remove it from the original dataframe, then merge it back without duplicate. Depends on what you want exactly

Comment: I just want for each var1 to have only the first var2 wich it occurs with.
so like the duplicates of var1 would be combined under one var2

Comment: see update, but you're losing information here ;)